# How do I view the contents of PostMessage()?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

While debugging a web app that uses `window.opener.postMessage()` I noticed Fiddler was not showing traffic for the PostMessage event. How does `PostMessage()` work and how can I view the messages being sent between the two pages?

Comment: `postMessage` doesn't send to the server, it's just internal within the browser.

Answer (score 1):

See the MDN docs for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Fiddler won't show traffic because it can only sniff what happens between your browser and the rest of the network. In `postMessage` it all happens between frames and windows on the same machine, and no network traffic occurs.

One way to see what is happening would be to use `console.log(e);` calls inside your `postMessage` handlers so you can see the results in the dev tools console.